# Is it possible to control EAGER/LAZY loading outside of a model?

Tags: java, spring

We're using Spring Framework and are setting up a site that will communicate directly with the service layer of the application via jersey.  We're running into scenarios where certain things in our models are lazy loaded (as we need them to be) but we'd like to be able to "flip a switch" within a service or dao that tells the model to fetch the model eagerly so we don't have to write a bunch of code to fetch the relationships that we need.

Is this possible?

Comment: If you don't want to use the Hibernate APIs, then you can access the lazily loaded property in the same session (usually within the DAO method). For collections, you'll have to call something like `size()` on it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can override this for example using `Criteria`'s `FetchMode`:

```
List parents = session.createCriteria(Parent.class)
.add( Restrictions.like("prop", value) )
.setFetchMode("childs", FetchMode.EAGER)
.list();
```

This will load the *childs* property collection eagerly even if by default it's lazily fetched

Comment: Thanks for the feedback.  I probably shouldn't have tagged this with hibernate.  Is there a spring solution?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know of any pre-built stuff that will do this for you and don't feel like googling for it, but I can imagine a setup that you could code...

- Loadable interface for your POJOs that you want to flip back and forth...
- Slot class that wraps all of your classes slots.  Slot could have a method Slot.load() which would tell the slot to load.  Natively, Slot would lazy load.  This class may require lots of time and lots of subclasses to get right...
- SlotLoader abstract class whose purpose is to tell the Slot when to load.  Has abstract method onAssign().  Has final method assign(Slot slot) that assigns the loader to a slot and calls onAssign.
- LazyLoader class implements SlotLoader.  when onAssign() is called, do nothing
- EagerLoader class implements SlotLoader.  when onAssign() is called, slot.load() is called.

All of your methods that you want to switch back and forth would need to be re-coded to wrap their slots with Slot, and your Spring configuration would need to know whether to use LazyLoader or EagerLoader.